# Running python code on a webpage

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, applet, jython

I have a python code that uses a gui (tkinter) and I would like to be able to use it on a website.
How can this be done?
For the code to work on my laptop I had to do a pip download nltk so this would also need to be done.

Many thanks,
Reuben

Comment: You cannot run tkinter code on a webpage. Only webpage code (HTML, CSS, Javascript) will run on a webpage.

Comment: @Novel Will java work? If so how would I then put it on a web page?

Comment: No, Java does not run on a webpage either. However Python (or Java) can be used to generate HTML, using a "web framework" like Django or Flask.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a [Java applet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) in a browser. And you can write the applet in Python and compile it to Java byte code using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/). But you cannot use Tkinter and other GUI libraries in applets.

Answer (score 1):

For a different approach a Tkinter GUI can be displayed in a webpage by the use of noVNC (HTML5 vncviewer), an Xvnc server (like TigerVNC) and a window manager (like matchbox-window-manager). At the server end per request you need a webserver configured to launch an Xdisplay via Xvnc, the window manager and the Tkinter gui using the same Xdisplay. You can configure a web page to use an iframe HTML tag to display the Tkinter GUI via noVNC. For an example of this check out CloudTk. It is written in Tcl using TclHttpd but I am sure this can be duplicated in Python. It shows a Tkinter GUI displayed in a web page using iframes but the code is executed on the server. Go to

https://wiki.tcl.tk/41972

Comment: Is there a step by step tutorial for this?